# RestFb - For Events, description and multiple other fields are coming null

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

This is my code

```
public class RestFbTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(ACCESS_TOKEN);
    Connection<Event> search = facebookClient.fetchConnection("search", Event.class, Parameter.with("q", "Bengaluru"), Parameter.with("type", "event"));
    int c=0;
    for (List<Event> searchList : search) {
        for (Event event : searchList) {

        System.out.println("Event: " + event);
        }
    }

    }

}
```

Event Id's are showing up in the list.
Eg., this is the first event ID : 149517752101309
The description for this is null in the list.
But on web I can see the description

[Description of Id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2hra.png)

My access token has the following scopes : user_events, public_profile

Why is restFb not capturing the description?

Comment: Just checked this with your code and I see the description. I even don't use any special permission.

Comment: That's weird.
Anyway, I have already written my own functions to get the data.

Comment: could u provide your function how to check is null or not? I am facing the same problem.